Calculation of Radiation Energy in Peskin&Schroeder
In Peskin&Schroeder QFT section 6.1, they try to compute the radiation energy of soft bremsstrahlung classically where the momentum-space amplitude of vector potential is
$$\mathcal{A}^{\mu}(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{-e}{|\mathbf{k}|}\left(\frac{p'^{\mu}}{k\cdot p'}-\frac{p^{\mu}}{k\cdot p}\right) \tag{6.7}$$
The momentum-space amplitude of the radiation field are
$$\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{k}) = -i\mathbf{k}\mathcal{A}^0(\mathbf{k})+ik^{0}\mathcal{A}(\mathbf{k})\tag{6.8}$$
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathbf{k}) = i\mathbf{k}\times\mathcal{A}(\mathbf{k})\tag{6.8}$$
and the energy after several calculation
$$\text{Energy} = \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\, \mathcal{E}(\mathbf{k})\cdot\mathcal{E}^*(\mathbf{k})}\tag{6.11}$$
They introduce two transverse unit polarization vectors and the part parallel to $\mathbf{k}$ in $\mathcal{E}$ vanishes,
$$\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{k})\cdot\mathcal{E}^*(\mathbf{k}) = \sum_{\lambda = 1, 2}|\mathbf{\epsilon}_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k})\cdot\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{k})|^2 = |\mathbf{k}|^2\sum_{\lambda = 1, 2}|\mathbf{\epsilon}_{\lambda}(\mathbf{k})\cdot\mathcal{A}(\mathbf{k})|^2$$
In the following calculation, they claim we can freely change $\mathbf{\epsilon}, \mathbf{p}, \text{and }\mathbf{p'}$ into 4-vectors in this expression, which confused me.
Can anyone explain why we can extand 3-vectors into 4-vectors here?

Pesky and Shredder is really not for beginners. As an introduction to QFT it is a failure; its renormalisation chapter is good, though. However, your problem is a standard move in SR, and you should have seen many physics quantities upgraded from 3D to 3+1D equivalents, before you start QFT.

It is just the gauge choice that the time component of the vector field doesn’t have corresponding canonical momentum, and thus we have the time component of polarization is always $0$ (or equivalently $A^0=0$), so we can upgrade 3D to 3D+1D without worrying this would affect the equation.
